# in jsp,how to bypass the URL using http proxy

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

In my jsp page(say sample.jsp), it has some links like Google.com.if i click Google.com link, it should connect to another web server via http proxy.How to implement this.

Comment: It's not very clear what you are trying to achieve. You cannot control the proxy sever configuration on the client browser from your web page.

Answer (score 0):

The jsp page will use your browser proxy settings . You can't define your own proxy settings unless you are hitting the link from an application(not browser).

Answer (score 0):

the link will take use the proxy settings that are configured in your browser.  The only way I know how to use a different proxy for a different URL would be to setup a PAC file that specifies what proxy to use for a given URL or I.P. range.  The PAC file is hosted on a web server and referenced in your browsers network configurations.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The only way would be to have *your server* be the proxy. That's what Google and Facebook do to get some datas about the links you click.

For example, if there is a Google.com link, make it a link like http://yourserver.com/proxy.jsp?link=http://www.google.com.

This way, you can do whatever you want, and then redirect to the link provided.